# Arguments are of the wrong type with Stored Procedure Parameters

Tags: stored-procedures, parameters, asp-classic, vbscript, adodb

Im using a stored procedure to return a product price where i send two parameters to it, ones the stockcode and the other is like the customer number. When i run this is get the following error

```
ADODB.Command error '800a0bb9'

Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict 
with one another.
```

The two parameters i send a both strings and they can both vary in length.

The code is as follows.

```
bnno = request("bn")
stockcode = request("ht")

dim prices

   Set cn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
   cn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=stock;"&_
"User Id=username;Password=password;"
   Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
   Set cmd.ActiveConnection = cn
   Set prices = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
   cmd.CommandText = "sp_stockdata"
   cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
   cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("htcode", adlongvarchar, _
      adParamReturnValue)
   cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("bn", adlongvarchar, _
      adParamInput)

   cmd("htcode") = stockcode
   cmd("bn") = bnno

   set prices = cmd.Execute
```

Can someone please help me change this code so i can send the text to the parameters??

Comment: What data types does the stored procedure expect?

Answer (score 1):

adParamReturnValue parameters can only be numeric. To return other kind of data, please read [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188655%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) (and select your sqlserver version)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the stored procedure in a wrong way. As mentioned in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20075385/447356), `adParamReturnValue` means "use the stored procedure return value" which can only be a numeric code.

<strike>Looks like what you're really after is *output parameter*, which is 2 aka `adParamOutput`. You also can't assign output parameter to local variable like that.</strike>
After second reading I understand the above isn't correct, leaving it for others who might get confused in similar way.

What you really want as far as I can see is just send two input parameters, so proper code would be:

```
cmd.CommandText = "sp_stockdata"
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("htcode", adLongVarChar, adParamInput, Len(stockcode), stockcode)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("bn", adLongVarChar, adParamInput, Len(bnno), bnno)
set prices = cmd.Execute
```

Note that you must also specify the data length when using `adLongVarChar` type.